# Проблемы с экспортированием переменной из модуля

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет.
Столкнулся с проблемой экспортирования переменной(из модуля).

Код можно увидеть на скриншоте.(и по ссылке на [Github](https://github.com/Mike-Kharkov/Vue-testing/tree/ece727ef3dd19e465921ae986d9c65b6fa22eac1).)
Есть 2 модуля:

1-й ServerDetails.vue
2-й main.js

Переменную('eventServer2') из первого модуля импортировать не составляет никакого труда.
Со вторым модулем('main.js') большая проблема.
Какие бы пути я не прописывал - экспортироваться переменная('eventServer') на отрез отказывается.

Вопрос:
Что я делаю не так?
(прохожу сейчас один курс и там такой метод(и путь) подключения вполне работоспособен.)

Буду благодарен за любой конструктивный совет..

[image: Код в редакторе.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По пунктам:
 1. Вам же в консоли ясно написано, **can't resolve**, что значит - не могу найти файл `main.js` по указанному адресу. Как только вы положите его туда, откуда пытаетесь взять - все заработает, но...
 2. Ваш файл `main.js` используется для подключения инстанса Vue, как я понимаю. И экспортировать из него какие-то переменные - это ну совсем не логичный ход. Я бы на вашем месте оставил `main.js` для `new Vue(...)` и все, что с этим связано. А если вам нужно использовать что-то и в `main.js`, и в `Servers.vue` - заведите для этого отдельный модуль.

Comment: "Как только вы положите его туда, откуда пытаетесь взять - все заработает"
- а если я к примеру именно от туда хочу экспортировать - то какой путь(как(или что) конкретно) необходимо прописать в файле с импортом, который в данном примере на скриншоте?

Comment: `../../main.js` для вашего случая

Comment: @ПавелГалкин, а как такой путь получился? `Servers.vue` лежит в `Server`, тогда `..` даст `components` и как раз там лежит `main.js`. Насколько я вижу, путь в вопросе верный. Как ты получил, что надо `../../main.js`?

Comment: @Qwertiy это VSCode так криво показывает дерево =) На самом деле App.vue и main.js лежат в src

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте.

Дело в том, что файл `main.js` не является модулем. Проверить это легко: в файле модуля есть ключевое слово `export`, отвечающее именно за экспорт кода из модуля.

Для получения переменной из файла `main.js` советую использовать код вида `this.$root.eventServer`, где `$root` означает перейти в корневой компонент, именно в тот, который объявляется в файле `main.js`

Comment: [http://joxi.ru/brRgJP5hQjbGKm](http://joxi.ru/brRgJP5hQjbGKm)
А как же тогда получается, что в уроке все корректно экспортируется?
[http://joxi.ru/nAypkNxHXonDY2](http://joxi.ru/nAypkNxHXonDY2)

Comment: @Idushii вы в корне неправы. `export default` - это дефолтный экспорт. `export` - именованный. Оба работают, но немного по-разному.

Comment: Поправлюсь: `main.js`, созданный по умолчанию в vue-cli, не является модулем. Для экспортирования необходимо указывать ключевое слово `export`. И да, ошибка не в этом.